# Read in variable length integer matrix

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to read in the file

```
10 5 6 78 5 120 5 6 84 9 5 1
1 3 2 4 5 2 3 4 1 2 1 3
1 4 7 8 12 13
```

With a variable length of the rows.

I attempt to count the number of elements in a column first by reading in one number at a time, but it seems as if every call to read moves me to the next line. Is there an easy way to count the number of elements in an individual line in Fortran?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You really should post your code. You cannot just ask for someone to write a code for you even though you were successful in finding someone this time.

Comment: It is very likely that your program _is_ advancing to the next line (/record).  Are you using `advance='no'` in the input statement?  [As others have said, please show your code.]

Answer (score 2):

Check if this helps -

```
program count_words_text 
implicit none 
integer, parameter   :: nlen=1000 
character (len=nlen) :: text 
integer              :: nwords, pos, i 
  text = "foo boo 1 2 goo" 
  pos = 1 
  nwords = 0 
  loop: do 
    i = verify(text(pos:), ' ')  !-- Find next non-blank. 
    if (i == 0) exit loop        !-- No word found. 
    nwords = nwords + 1          !-- Found something. 
    pos = pos + i - 1            !-- Move to start of the word. 
    i = scan(text(pos:), ' ')    !-- Find next blank. 
    if (i == 0) exit loop        !-- No blank found. 
    pos = pos + i - 1            !-- Move to the blank. 
  end do loop 
  print*,nwords ! gives 5 
end program count_words_text
```